# Saving data for user chat log between different pages, facebook style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I currently have a chat interface like facebook at the very bottom of my page.  You can click on your contacts and initiate a chat with them.  I currently do not store the chat messages in a database because I simply just relay one message from one browser to another using signalR, doing some tag stripping etc.  If the user navigates to another page on the website, what is a good strategy of saving the user's open chats, and their chat history for those open chat windows?  Should I use a database for this anyway? or is there another way to just store it in session maybe, but i could see how that could take up a lot of memory on the server.

If you do suggest a database for this, would something like mongoDB or sql server be a better choice for something like this.

*Keep in mind the chat data is not that important to me, i would just like a little bit of a conversation to be saved for each chat the user opens up , so if he or she starts browsing the website, the chat bar can still pick up where it left off on ANY page and pick up the data from the chat.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the messages server-side, I'd recommend keeping the last X messages in localStorage on the client side: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage